# Get updated tasks log after redeploy via API in TFS 2017

Tags: api, release-management

I'm using the TFS 2017 API to get the latest deploy log for my releases.

I'm using this pattern:

```
GET https://{instance}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}/tasks?api-version={version}
```

It works well for the first deployment.

When a task fails, and I redeploy it, it returns the log of the **first** deployment, not the current deployment.

I want the log of the last deployment for each task, not the first deployment.

Comment: You should make your question clear and explicit in the body of your question. What, exactly, do you want help to achieve?

Comment: I edited the question and now it's clearer

Comment: @ShaiCohen How do you redeploy it when a task failed? Assuming you are using Release to deploy, normally the release will be also failed once a task  is failed. When you redeploy, it will be a new release,So get the log with the new release ID. Please correctly me if I misunderstood.

Comment: @MSFT I press on the redeploy button and it's the same releaseID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the deployPhases in the Rest API URL:

```
GET https://{instance}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}/deployPhases/{deployPhaseId}/tasks?api-version={version}
```

For example, if you deploy the environment three times and you want to get the information for the third deployment, then the `deployPhaseId` is `3`.